# How to Create Action method to Apply Job in Mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a table called ApplyJob in my database. But my question is how to create a method which can populate the information for each job/user in the database. Any help is much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace TopJobs.Models
{
    public class ApplyJob
    {
        [Key]
        public int a_Id { get; set; }

        public int? UserId { get; set; }

        public long po_ID { get; set; } 

        public virtual UserProfile UserPro { get; set; }

        public virtual PostJob Postjobs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You wrote your Model.Then you have to create a controller to use it. Here is how to create controller and actions in MVC. [Controllers and Actions on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you eould need to do is create a view where you can enter the information that you would like to save in the database via Linq. the view would look something like this:

```
@model TopJobs.Models.ApplyJob

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Job";
}

<div class="container">
    <h2>Create Job</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("NameOfCreateActionHere", "NameOfControllerHere", FormMethod.Post,     new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.po_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.po_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.po_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    //Continue doing this for the rest of the elements in your model
    }
</div>
```

You will then need to create an action in your controller which will read in this information from your model and save it to your database. this action could look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "a_Id,UserId,po_ID,UserPro,Postjobs")] ApplyJob applyJob)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.TableNameHere.Add(applyJob);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(applyJob);
}
```

Where db is the instance of your database. This is just one possible way of doing it. Hope this helps.

Comment: i know how to save Value in database ,my problem is jobseeker apply job  then click apply button current jobseeker userId(login id) & empolyer po_Id (post jobs Id)   save in database